# Using JRuby with Oracle Database to populate a database

Tags: oracle, jruby

I am looking to populate a database using jruby. I followed the instructions [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/jruby-oracle11g-330825.html) and I have updates and queries working great. My issue is with the initial population of the database. The initial population is done using sqlplus calling the following sql script:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION createLcid RETURN varchar2 IS
  hexval varchar2(64);
  digit  number;
  hexdigit  char;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..32 loop
     digit := TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.value(1,16));
     if digit > 9 then 
       hexdigit := chr(ascii('a') + digit - 10);
     else
       hexdigit := to_char(digit);
     end if;
     hexval := hexval || hexdigit;
  end loop;
  return hexval;
END createLcid;
/ 

BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1..50 LOOP
      INSERT INTO as_dcm_testing VALUES (createLcid(), to_char(systimestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF1'),    TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.value(100000,999999999)), 'VL' || to_char(TRUNC(DBMS_RANDOM.value(1,9))));
   END LOOP;
   COMMIT;
END;
/

PROMPT Complete
PROMPT *************************************************************************

EXIT;
```

I want to replace the sqlplus call with an OracleConnection call as in the documentation but running as a prepare_call or an execute_query as in the examples does not seem to update the table. Running sqlplus does.

I tried 
reading in the file as text and passing it to prepare_call/execute_update and execute_query (no errors - table not updated),
reading in the file as text, splitting it on ; and passing each line in the array to prepare_call/execute_update and execute_query (no errors - table not updated), 
creating a helper call in the main class with the contents on the sql file in it and passing it to prepare_call/execute_update and execute_query (no errors - table not updated).

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or has anybody got a different approach using the jdbc driver?

A

Answer (score 0):

One of the approaches is to replace your pl/sql function with sql.
Then you will be able to execute pure sql script right from JRuby in a loop:

```
select 
    to_char(trunc(dbms_random.value(1,power(16, 32))), lpad('x', 32, 'x'))
from dual;
```

Is there a reason for not including zero into random pick?